# Передача файлов по сети С++

Tags: c++, сокеты

### Передаю файлы на сервер вот так:

```
const int _size=4096;
char _buf[_size];

FILE* file;
file = fopen(address.c_str(), "rb");
int BytesRead = 0;
while (!feof(file)) {
    ZeroMemory(_buf, _size);
    BytesRead = fread(_buf, 1, _size, file);
    if (BytesRead > 0) {
        send(_skt, _buf, BytesRead, 0); // send data
        cout << BytesRead << endl;
        ZeroMemory(_buf, _size);
        recv(_skt, _buf, _size, 0);     // receive SUCCESS
    }
}
send(_skt, "eof", 3, 0);            // send eof
fclose(file);
cout << "transmitting successful" << endl;
```

Сервер пишет файлы в определенную папку. Текстовые файлы копируются таким образом на сервер без проблем. Размер и содержимое совпадает. Но с `.exe` беда. Проблема в отправке. Если разделить размер файла на размер буфера, то количество отправок не совпадает с реальным. В итоге файлы пишутся едва ли на 10% от своего размера и, конечно же, не работают. Где ошибка ?

### Принимаю вот так:

```
#define FAIL "-1"
#define SUCCESS "0"

fstream IncFile;
IncFile.open(FileName, fstream::out);
int nbytes = 0;
while (1) {
    ZeroMemory(_buf, _size);
    nbytes = recv(sock, _buf, _size, 0);
    if (nbytes == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cout << GetTime() << "\tERROR while receive: "
            << WSAGetLastError()
            << "\tsocket " << sock << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if ((string)_buf != "eof") {
        IncFile << _buf;
        send(sock, SUCCESS, strlen(SUCCESS), 0);
    }
    else
        break;
}
IncFile.close();
```

Comment: а теперь подумай, что случится, если в файле будет строка `eof`.

Comment: проверяю при приеме

Comment: Ошибка была в том, что отправляю, используя FILE* file, а принимаю через fstream. Переделал и передачу и прием через FILE* file и все заработало. Наверно еще дело было в том, что передавал в двоичном формате, а принимал не в двоичном.